# Take data of a sound wave and use as representation in the distortion of images, video, or 3d?

Tags: audio, video, images, automation, 3d

I've become very fascinated with the idea of digital destruction through a physical medium.  There was PBS video on youtube **[How Does Glitchy Art Show Us Broken Is Beautiful?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MCmBHPqz6I&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PL69BD06CC757E1D61)**

**Example Pieces:**

[Cultural Brazilian sound chair](http://www.dezeen.com/2012/07/13/noize-chairs-by-estudio-guto-requena/): 
shows this idea with sound and how a sound of brazil influence the form.

[Digital cabinet](http://www.dezeen.com/2013/03/14/good-vibrations-distorted-cabinet-ferruccio-laviani-fratelli-boffi/). Shows a split between the classical baroque cabinetry and new digital destruction.

---

---

### Question:

- how can I capture a sound wave data graphically and from this edit an image, video or 3d rendeR

  - Are there any common: tools or process to achieving these kind of results from the example?
- Any automation of these effects through java (any language for tha tmatter) would be the most useful in this representation?

  *I believe that the automation is what will form beautiful*

---

I'm a pretty good programmer so any concepts on automation of stuff like this would be excellent.  I know this is a really wonky question but any tips or trick will help me in my research.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can obtain a sound wave data graphically using [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

For automation, you may take a look at [LADSPA](http://www.ladspa.org/).

Hope it helps